# How to iterate and remove elements from hashset most effective way

Tags: c#, .net, loops, hashset

Ok here what i came up with but i wonder is it most effective way. I need to do this for ram memory issues.

```
HashSet<string> hsLinks = new HashSet<string>();
List<string> lstSortList = new List<string>();

// fill hashset with millions of records

while (true)
{
    string srLastitem = "";
    foreach (var item in hsLinks)
    {
        srLastitem = item;
        break;
    }
    lstSortList.Add(srLastitem);
    hsLinks.Remove(srLastitem);
    if (hsLinks.Count == 0)
        break;
}
```

c# .net 4.5.2 wpf application

Comment: first of is there anything preventing you from using **hsLinks.first()** instead of that foreach loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're trying to move items from the `HashSet` to the `List`. If that's the case simply move everything once with [`List.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use `HashSet.Clear` to empty the `HashSet`:

```
lstSortList.AddRange(hsLinks);
hsLinks.Clear();
```

If (as Vajura suggested) you're worried about holding on to 2 copies of **the references*** you can instead move batches instead of single items:

```
const int batchSize = 1000;
var batch = new string[batchSize];
do
{
    var batchIndex = 0;
    foreach (var link in hsLinks.Take(batchSize))
    {
        batch[batchIndex] = link;
        batchIndex++;
    }

    if (batchIndex < batchSize)
    {
        batch = batch.Take(batchIndex).ToArray();
    }

    hsLinks.ExceptWith(batch);
    lstSortList.AddRange(batch);
} while (hsLinks.Any());
```

Use batches in an appropriate size for you memory concerns.

---

*Note: A reference is 4 or 8 bytes in size (on 32bit and 64bit respectively). When you add the strings (which are reference types in .Net) to the list you are not copying them, only the references (which are mostly negligible).

Comment: well this would double the amount of ram used before Clear() is called as that seems to be the issue?

Comment: @Vajura Only if the objects in the list are structs, if they are classes you would only have the references copied which do not take up as much space.

Comment: @Vajura it would copy the references, which isn't a big deal. But I addressed that in the answer as well.

Comment: Yea but in this case they are strings so they do get copied

Comment: @Vajura No, `string` isn't a struct in .Net.

Comment: while it isnt a struct i am pretty sure that copying a string into another string or adding it to a list is always a deep copy

Comment: ah yes that batch way is what i am looking for . it looks better. first way would double ram memory usage :)

Comment: @Vajura No. There's no mechanism to do that in .Net.

Comment: @Vajura No it won't. It will just copy the reference (roughly the address) of string.

Comment: @Vajura No. `string`s are immutable in .NET, so the runtime can do a lot of optimizations on their references. You *can* have two strings with the same value, but you can't just take a reference to one string and "deep copy" it somewhere else. It's just that whenever you use an operation such as `+`, you are creating a *new* string. In this case, it will clearly only copy the references, so the memory use will be negligible (links are probably a lot longer than 4 bytes).

Comment: @Luaan 8 on 64bit. :)

Comment: @Luaan so first way would not double the memory usage can you test this ?

Comment: I think i am going to test this lets see :)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG It will not copy the actual content of the strings, only the references. For a million items on a 64bit machine that would be less than 8mb in size. I've added the explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Luaan well i tried 10 million links and it increased from 2.403.248.168 to 2.563.272.872 i used          long gcCollect = GC.GetTotalMemory(false); method to calculate. I dont know 10m should make 8.000.000 however difference is 160.024.704

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG 10,000,000 items should be 80,000,000 bytes. You can clearly see that the strings themselves are not being copied. Just the references are.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG 80M (you missed a zero) vs. 160M isn't such a big difference. In any case, measuring memory usage in a managed application is a lot harder than that, and copying in parts will very likely result in higher memory usage (you need to handle all the arrays of intermediate size).

Comment: @Luaan you are correct yes seems like references copied :)  ty for answers

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG btw, I've updated the batch example to use less memory. You can check that again if you want. It would probably shrink the difference to 80m.

Comment: @Luaan My guess is that the extra 80m comes from the new batch instances being used each time that (probably) were not collected. This will amount to the entire List . I've updated the example with using a single array.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to move the items from `hsLinks` to `lstSortList` (and clear `hsLinks` afterwards), this is where you would want to use [`List<T>.AddRange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
lstSortList.AddRange(hsLinks);
hsLinks.Clear();
```

Comment: ty but this would double ram usage before copy so imagine if i had 6 gb ram and hashset uses 4 gb ram :)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG see the discussion in the [above answer's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29099824/996081) comments

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG It will not. It will only copy the references, not the string values - about 4-8 bytes per item. Since you're working with links (which tend to be a lot longer than 2-4 characters), you will not even see the difference, really.